# sklearn cross_val_score() returns NaN values

Tags: python, nan, prediction, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas

i'm trying to predict next customer purchase to my job. I followed a guide, but when i tried to use cross_val_score() function, it returns NaN values.[Google Colab notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHGzs.png)

Variables:

- X_train is a dataframe
- X_test is a dataframe
- y_train is a list
- y_test is a list

Code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=50)
X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)
X_train
X_test = X_test.reset_index(drop=True)

y_train = y_train.astype('float')
y_test = y_test.astype('float')

models = []
models.append(("LR",LogisticRegression()))
models.append(("NB",GaussianNB()))
models.append(("RF",RandomForestClassifier()))
models.append(("SVC",SVC()))
models.append(("Dtree",DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(("XGB",xgb.XGBClassifier()))
models.append(("KNN",KNeighborsClassifier()))´

for name,model in models:
   kfold = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=22)
   cv_result = cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train, cv = kfold,scoring = "accuracy")
   print(name, cv_result)
>>
LR [nan nan]
NB [nan nan]
RF [nan nan]
SVC [nan nan]
Dtree [nan nan]
XGB [nan nan]
KNN [nan nan]
```

help me please!

Comment: When you have a NaN error, that means there is a number that are not given in the function. U should review that

Comment: Please include your code in formatted text with your question. A picture of code is about as useful as a picture of music...

Comment: There is probably a problem with your data. In documentation to sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score, X_train can be a list, or an array, and in your case, X_train is a dataframe. Try to use X_train.values in cross_val_score instead of X_train.

Comment: try with cv = 5. cv should be an int, not a kfold object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks everyone for your answers. The answer of Anna helped me a lot!, but i don't used X_train.values, instead i assigned an unique ID to the Customers, then dropped Customers column and it works!

Now the models has this output :)

```
LR [0.73958333 0.74736842]
NB [0.60416667 0.71578947]
RF [0.80208333 0.82105263]
SVC [0.79166667 0.77894737]
Dtree [0.82291667 0.83157895]
XGB [0.85416667 0.85263158]
KNN [0.79166667 0.75789474]
```

Comment: Hey man, I'm dealing with this issue as well, could you explain a bit further as to what you did

Comment: I am having the same issue, I have built a pipeline and fitting it to data. If I fit separately it gives me the accuracy score but if I try cross validation it is showing NaN values. Can u please share how to debug?

Answer (score 7):

My case is a bit different. I was using `cross_validate` instead of `cross_val_score` with a list of performance metrics. Doing a 5 fold CV, I kept getting NaNs for all performance metrics for a `RandomForestRegressor`:

```
scorers = ['neg_mean_absolute_error', 'neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'r2', 'accuracy']

results = cross_validate(forest, X, y, cv=5, scoring=scorers, return_estimator=True)
results
```

Turns out, I stupidly included the 'accuracy' metric which is only used in classification. Instead of throwing an error, it looks like sklearn just returns NaNs for such cases

Comment: I've just done the same. A validity check within Sklearn would seem sensible.

Comment: This error can come up if you are using `cross_validate` in general, the `pos_label` parameter has been removed and moved instead to the `make_scorer` function, so for scores like precision and recall, you will need to create your own scorer with `make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label='pos')` to get it working, otherwise your scores will be NaNs.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the issue on my side. I was using a custom metric (Area Under Curve Precision-Recall (AUCPR))

```
def pr_auc_score(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
  classes = list(range(y_pred.shape[1]))
  if len(classes) == 2:
      precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y, y_pred[:,1],
                                                    **kwargs)
  else:
    Y = label_binarize(y, classes=classes)
    precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(Y.ravel(), y_pred.ravel(),
                                                  **kwargs)
  return auc(recall, precision)
```

The problem is, for a binary problem, `y_pred` contains only the predicted probability of the label 1, so `y_pred`'s shape is (n_sample,).
When I try to call the method : `y_pred.shape[1]`, it raises an error.

**The solution:** inside `cross_validate`, use the parameter `error_score="raise"`. This will allow you to detect the error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered already but for others who still cannot figure out the problem, this is for you...

Check if you `y` data type is a `int` or not. It will return `nan` if your date type for the `y` value is an `object`

#### How to check

`y.dtype`

#### How to change the data type

`y = y.astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I had a time delta data type inside my numpy array that resulted in the error

Answer (score 0):

I face to face with that problem. I solved this way; i convert X_train and y_train to DataFrame.

```
cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train, cv = kfold,scoring = "accuracy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing encoding of categorical columns before passing to cross_val_score. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The `cross_val_score` method returns `NaN` when there are null values in your dataset.

Either use a model which can deal with missing values or remove all the null values from your dataset and try again.

Answer (score -2):

For me using `xtrain.values`, `ytrain.values` worked as the cross validation needs the input to be an array and not dataframe.